# Date formatting in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, view-helpers

I have a date in one of my models, which I am currently rendering in my simple form with

```
<%= f.input :issue_date, label:false %>
```

This, I believe automatically applies the `date_select` helper, causing it to render three very nice selection fields: one for day, one for month one for year.

**The problem** is that I really can't stand using select for the day and year (just seems more efficient to type it).  Is there a good way to change the rendering of these fields?  I really like how convenient this automatic rendering is; I'd just like it to render with one select box and two text boxes.  Thanks for any suggestions.